# Gradient of Quadratic Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, matrix-calculus

I'm currently considering a problem where we have data vectors $X_1,\dots,X_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$ with labels $y_i=\pm1$. I want to find the minimizer of $L(\theta)=\sum_i(1-y_iX_i^t\theta)^2$ by finding the derivative and setting it equal to $0$. My attempt so far is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L(\theta)}{\partial \theta} = -2\sum_i(1-y_iX_i^t\theta)y_iX_i=0\\
\iff\sum_iy_iX_i=\sum_iX_i^t\theta X_i.
\end{equation}

If this is correct, how do I solve for $\theta$ here? I know $\theta$ doesn't depend on $i$, but my understanding is that I can't pull it out of the sum since it's a vector. I have gone as far as calculating the Hessian matrix $H$:

\begin{equation}
[H]_{jk}=\frac{\partial^2L(\theta)}{\partial\theta_j\partial\theta_k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_k}\frac{\partial L(\theta)}{\partial\theta_j}\\
= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_k}\left(-2\sum_i(y_iX_{ij}-X_{ij}X_i^t\theta)\right)\\
= 2\sum_iX_{ij}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_k}X_i^t\theta\right)\\
=2\sum_iX_{ij}X_{ik}\\
=2X^tX.
\end{equation}
where $X=[X_1^t,\dots,X_n^t]^t\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ (called the design matrix in statistics). This shows $H$ is PSD, so therefore the $\theta$ I'm looking for is a minimizer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}\def\L{{\cal L}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Let's use a convention wherein lower/uppercase letters denote vectors/matrices (respectively) and define the following variables
$$\eqalign{
&X = \m{x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_n} &\qiq \;X\in\bbR{d\times n} \\
&\o = {\rm all\;ones\;vector} &\qiq \;\;\o\in\bbR{n} \\
&w = \theta &\qiq \;\,w\in\bbR{d} \\
&Y = \Diag y=Y^T &\qiq Y\o=y\in\bbR{n}\\
&v = \LR{YX^Tw - \o} &\qiq \;dv = YX^Tdw \\
}$$
Now the objective function can be written without using any $\Sigma$ symbols, making the gradient calculation considerably easier
$$\eqalign{
\L &= v^Tv \\
d\L &= 2v^T\c{dv} \;=\; 2v^T\CLR{YX^Tdw} \;=\; \LR{2XYv}^Tdw \\
\grad{\L}{w} &= 2XYv \;=\; 2\LR{XY^2X^Tw-Xy} \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $w$-vector
$$\eqalign{
XY^2X^Tw &= Xy \qiq
w &= \LR{XY^2X^T}^{-1}Xy \\
}$$

### Update

The elements $\,y_k=\pm\o\implies Y^2=I,\,$
so the final result can be simplified to
$$\eqalign{
w &= \LR{XX^T}^{-1}Xy \\
}$$
Also, the way I've defined $X$ makes it the transpose
of the *Design Matrix*.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there anything you saw wrong with my calculation, either of the first derivative or of the Hessian? Is there a reasonable way to find the optimal $\theta$ from my calculation?

Comment: @Jake I really don't know. I have trouble interpreting formulas involving summations unless they strictly observe the summation convention (aka index notation). So nothing that takes powers of indexed quantities, e.g. $\;x_k^3\;$

Comment: Which part doesn't obey that convention? Is it the $X_i^t$? By $t$ I mean transpose, same as $X_i^T$.

Comment: @Jake Okay, I see a symbol with no indexes $(\tt1)$ subtracted from a term with two indexes $(y_iX_i^T\theta)$ and the whole thing multiplied by a term carrying two more indexes $(y_iX_i).\;$  In index notation, an index which only appears once is called a _free index_ , an index which appears twice is called a _dummy index_ , and an index which appears three (or more) times is called a _mistake_ !  Another rule of thumb for index notation is that the _free indexes_ must match (in name and number) on both the LHS and RHS of an equation, but the (name and number of) _dummy indexes_ can differ.

Comment: Interesting. Math is crazy sometimes

Comment: Appreciate the update--this is actually the ordinary least squares solution for the vector $w$ (or $\theta$), which is quite familiar and makes sense. Writing the loss strictly in terms of vectors/matrices was helpful... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Jake, Regarding your question, your computations are all correct.

The only thing that is missing is to recognize
$$
\mathbf{x}_n^T \mathbf{w} \mathbf{x}_n
=
(\mathbf{x}_n \mathbf{x}_n^T) \mathbf{w}
$$
thus the RHS term writes
$$
\sum_n \mathbf{x}_n^T \mathbf{w} \mathbf{x}_n
=
\sum_n
(\mathbf{x}_n \mathbf{x}_n^T) \mathbf{w}
=
(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}) \mathbf{w}
$$

Comment: Ah, yes... $x_i^tw$ is a scalar so we can move it around. Thanks!